# Vertical overflow inside a flex-grow div in bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

im a bit noob in html web layout (im disclaiming this cause i have the feeling im probably making some rookie mistake) but this is driving me crazy and i have not been able to find a solution that works in my specific case

Im trying to make this layout for a future desktop app
[image]

This is my code

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>
    html, body { height: 100%; }
    .vh-100 {
        min-height: 100vh;
    }

    .height-100 {
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
    <div class="content">
        first menu
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        second menu
    </div>
    <div class="content bg-danger flex-grow-1">
        <div class="d-flex flex-row w-100 h-100">
            <div class="d-flex flex-column h-100 w-25">
                <div class="content bg-success">
                    first submenu
                </div>
                <div class="content overflow-auto">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur sapien leo, ornare ac dictum vel, feugiat in felis. Proin et nibh us orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Integer dolor tellus, sagittis sed felis sed, blandit pharetra nisi. Suspendisse suscipit consectetur nisi, vel interdum enim lacinia vel. Nulla placerat malesuada libero, vitae egestas metus interdum eu. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Integer consectetur porta augue ac suscipit.
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content bg-light w-75">
                more content
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="content bg-secondary">
        Footer
    </div>
</div>
```

Why the code is ignoring the overflow-auto in the content? How i can fix it? Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set max-height and overflow:hidden on the body:

```
body {
    height: 100vh;
    max-height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Then `overflow:auto` on the content to let it scroll as needed...

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
    <div class="content"> first menu </div>
    <div class="content"> second menu </div>
    <div class="content bg-danger flex-grow-1 overflow-auto">
        <div class="d-flex flex-row w-100 h-100">
            <div class="d-flex flex-column h-100 w-25">
                <div class="content bg-success"> first submenu </div>
                <div class="content overflow-auto"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur sapien leo, ornare ac dictum vel, feugiat in felis. Proin et nibh us orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Integer dolor tellus, sagittis sed felis sed, blandit pharetra nisi. Suspendisse suscipit consectetur nisi, vel interdum enim lacinia vel. Nulla placerat malesuada libero, vitae egestas metus interdum eu. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Integer consectetur porta augue ac suscipit. </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content bg-light w-75"> more content </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content bg-secondary"> Footer </div>
</div>
```

[Codeply demo](https://codeply.com/p/4JZbjmu2pB)